# How Do I Show All Of The List Title In That Div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sharepoint

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(ViewItem, 'sp.js');
    };

    function ViewItem() {

        var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        this.ListColl = ctx.get_web().get_lists();
        ctx.load(this.ListColl);
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFail));
    }

    function onSuccess(sender, args) {
        var listEnum = this.ListColl.getEnumerator();
        while (listEnum.moveNext()) {
            var oList = listEnum.get_current();
            document.getElementById('resultpanel').innerHTML = oList.get_title();
        }
    }

    function onFail(sender, args) {
        alert('FAIL!');
    }
</script>
<div id="resultpanel"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit cryptic with only text in Title and code in Body. I would suggest you go through - [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Now coming to the answer. If my guess is right then by 'That Div' you mean `<div id="resultpanel"></div>` and assuming your code is working to show Title of only one list then you would have to rework your code something like this:

```
var titleOfLists = "";
while (listEnum.moveNext()) {
    var oList = listEnum.get_current();
    titleOfLists = titleOfLists + oList.get_title() + ", ";
}
document.getElementById('resultpanel').innerHTML = titleOfLists;
```